# Encrypted images in an IMG tag

Tags: html, encryption

I am an unusual situation: my HTML is stored in a trusted place but my images are not.  What I would *like* to do is encrypt all my images before I store them and then put in the HTML something like

```
<img src="http://untrustedserver.com/encryptedimg.png.bz" password="0791e0cba50741"/>
```

If that were possible, it would be perfect: my clients, whom I trust, can see the image, but the image-store people cannot.

Is there some equivalent strategy, whereby the HTML can decrypt and display images?  I'm thinking of loading the data with Javascript and then putting the data into a `src="data:..."` attribute but that seems really cumbersome.

(Note: I trust the image-store to accurately serve the images I send them; I just don't want them looking at them.)

Comment: There are various javascript crypto libraries that will let you do what you want, SJCL comes to mind immediately. There is also the Webcrypto API that some browsers support.